How do I increase the font size in VS Code find widget?
I would like to be able to increase the font size of the tab in Visual Studio Code (or even the size of the tab if it increases the font size automatically) because I find it too small and I keep straining my eyes to see it.
The details are in the image:
enter image description here

There currently is not a built in way to increase the font size of the ctrl + f window specifically. Rather you'd have to increase the font size of your entire vscode by doing CTRL and + or Command and + or by increasing the editor font size in the settings.

At the time of this writing, the find widget has no font size setting.
There's an open feature-request issue ticket about this: Allow us to change the font type and size of find-replace widget #101064. I suggest that you give that issue ticket a thumbs up to show support for it. You can also subscribe to it to get notified about discussion and progress. Please avoid making noisy comments there like ones that just consist of "+1" / "bump".

Thank you! I don't know how you found this issue, but I'll do it as you recommended
